# Mysql portfolio Project "int is not in Valid Position"

Tags: mysql, r-portfolioanalytics

`select dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations

> SUM(CONVERT(int,vac.new_vaccinations)) OVER (Partition by dea.Location Order by dea.location, dea.Date) as RollingPeopleVaccinated from
> Portfolio.CovidDeaths as dea
> join portfolio.covidvaccine as vac
> on dea.location = vac.location and dea.date = vac.date
> where dea.continent is not null
> order by 2,3`

> 'SUM(CONVERT(signed int,vac.new_vaccinations)) error'
> 'I Tried The unsigned integer and signed int.'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`CAST`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp):

```
SUM(CAST(vac.new_vaccinations AS UNSIGNED))
```